# pagination dropdown options in Ajax js

Tags: ajax, jquery-select2

I have two select fields. `States and cities`. Displays a list of cities by state selection. But on Android phones, it appears very late(very slow). That's why I want to paginate.
how to pagination dropdown options in below my codes :

```
<script>
    $('#stateCode').on('change',function(){
    var stateID = $(this).val();    
    if(stateID){
        $('.spinner').show();
         $('#city').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        $.ajax({
           type:"get",
           dataType: 'json',
           url:"{{url('cityjson/get-city-listz')}}?state_id="+stateID,
           success:function(res){  
               $('.spinner').hide();
               $('#city').prop('disabled', false);
            if(res){
                $("#city").empty();
                $.each(res,function(key,value){
                    $("#city").append('<option value="'+value+'">'+key+'</option>');
                });
           
            }else{
               $("#city").empty();
            }
           }
        });
    }else{
        $("#city").empty();
    }
        
   });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select2 comes with AJAX support built in, using jQuery's AJAX methods.

Include all the js and css plugins. **Select2 4.0.0** or above needs to use.

**In your HTML:**

```
<select class="target" id="city"></select>
```

**Note for below JS**

- **items**: contains the data that will be used and option
- **item object**: each object contains {id:"1", test:"city 1"}
- **page**: current page number
- **total_count**: total number of cities for the state
- **term** : this param can be used to search.

**In your Javascript:**

```
$("#city").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "/cityjson/get-city-listz",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        state_id:stateID,
        page: params.page
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data, params) {
      params.page = params.page || 1;

      return {
        results: data.items,
        pagination: {
          more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
        }
      };
    },
    cache: true
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label>Client Details *</label>
    <input type="text" name="ClientId" id="ClientId" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
</body>
    
    <script>
    $.ajax({
            url: baseURL + 'getfile/ClientDetails',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',           
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);            
                var testdata = [{ id: 0, text: 'enhancement' }, { id: 1, text: 'bug' }, { id: 2, text: 'duplicate' }, { id: 3, text: 'invalid' }, { id: 4, text: 'wontfix' }];
                console.log(testdata);
                let data = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    //console.log(result[i]);
                    data.push.apply(data,result[i]);
                }
                console.log(data);
                     
    
    $("#ClientId").select2({
      data: data,
      minimumResultsForSearch: 20
    })
    
    }
    }); 
    
    </script>
    
  <?php  
     function ClientDetails() {
       
        $getAllClients = getdetails($id);
        $getAllClients = $getAllClients['Accountdetails'];
             
        $details = [];        
        foreach($getAllClients as $val){
            $id = $val['id'];
            $name = $val['client_name'];
            $details[] = array(
                'id' => $id,
                'text' => $name
            );
        }
            
        print_r(json_encode(array($details)));
    }
?>
```